# How can I open the screenshot folder in internal memory using intent in android?

Tags: android

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I know how to bring the image from the gallery but how can I access the DCIM/ScreenShot from the Internal Storage

Comment: `../DCIM/Screenshots,` Never seen such. You mean `.../Pictures/Screenshots`?

Comment: I have a galaxys8, and its screenshots folder path is that path in the phone. But when I access in Android Studio, it says sdcard/DCIM/Screenshots. Which is the true path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

The most you can get is the picker opening on the primary partion if it is an Android Q+ device.

But... For `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` you can put as extra in your intent an uri of a file the user choosed before.

Have a look at `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/"));//make sure the path points to the exact folder where screenshot is saved as there is no fixed disrectory for screenshot

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");

if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
{
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file 
    // explorer app installed on your device
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

There is a directory `DIRECTORY_SCREENSHOTS` but this require the minimum `sdk` level to `29`

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)


Uri uri = Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_SCREENSHOTS+"/"));

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");

  if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
     {
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!